# Is there any concrete evidence that Wright & Kleiman were involved or not involved in the creation of Bitcoin?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

Is there any cryptographically verifiable evidence that one or both Wright & Kleiman were or were not involved with the Satoshi Nakamoto character?

Looking for information related to Bitcoin keys, addresses, PGP keys, or any other type of cryptographic evidence. Information that disproves their involvement also welcome (faked PGP keys inserted into documents, etc), also welcome.

Comment: http://motherboard.vice.com/read/satoshis-pgp-keys-are-probably-backdated-and-point-to-a-hoax

Comment: That was a good read, thank you. I had seen Maxwell's post on Reddit, this blog post expanded on it and examined other attributes of the keys as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wright:
While his supposed credentials pointed at a polymath with a range of interests along the lines of what Satoshi must have studied, neither his contributions at a [recent discussion panel](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3w027x/dr_craig_steven_wright_alleged_satoshi_by_wired/cxsfy8p), nor his published work indicate that he has worked sufficiently on the main ideas of Bitcoin. Additionally, large parts of the corroborating evidence have [not been substantiated or outright disproven](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/544431/how-to-spot-bitcoin-inventor-satoshi-nakamoto/).

Kleiman:
After a career as a soldier, technician, deputy sheriff, and detective, Kleiman only switched to working with computers in 1995 (at 30) after a crash turned him paraplegic.
He then made career in computer forensics which, derived from the [list of his publications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Kleiman#Publications), seemingly focused on password security, data recovery, and Windows exploits. On January 1, 2007 he was named a Microsoft MVP for Windows - Security.

**It seems unlikely that Wright and Kleiman, whether solely or as a team could be the creators of Bitcoin.**

Edit: I just found out that the first version of Bitcoin was [Windows only](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41787/5406). So, maybe it is a shade more likely then.